# What's the best way to select an element between one element and one of its ancestor using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of nested tables (that let's assume I can't change the structure of) and I need to select the outermost td.

Test HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="relevanttable">
                <tr>
                    <td>one</td>
                    <td>two</td>
                    <td>
                        the important td
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>three - one</td>
                                <td>three - two <input id="targetinput" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var relevant_field = $('#targetinput');
var target_table = relevant_field.closest('.relevanttable');
// I want something like this
var important_cell = last_selected.closest('.relevanttable > tr > td');
```

I think I can get this done with relevant_field.parentsUntil('.tableanswer', 'td') then figuring out which item is the furthest from it, but I'm wondering if there's a better way of attacking this and immediately selecting the exact td I'm interested in. This is a simple example, but there may be multiple tables nested within each other and the outermost table might not be the one I'm concerned with.

updates in response to the first few comments/answer(s):

```
$('#targetInput').parents('td').last()
```

isn't quite right since there's possibly more nesting than is shown in my example. That is table > table > table.relevanttable (this one isn't important, only closest) > table.relevanttable > table > table >...> td

Also, to provide some context, data is going to be written to the table based on user interaction. Since it's user interaction, there's no way to know in advance what's going to be important. There may be a table.relevanttable within a table.relevanttable, but only the closest one should be used. Think of of it like pasting data into Excel, except that some excel cells contain entire sheets. It's Excel meets Inception.

Comment: This is a reasonable question but it leads me to ask for more info. What causes the necessity of the TD lookup? Is it user interaction or periodic update (via an async call) ?

Comment: The outermost TD could be reached by `$('#targetInput').parents('td').last()`... am I missing something?

Comment: The best way would be to give said important td something that you can select it by, such as a class.

Comment: @Matt [I don't think you're missing something...](http://jsfiddle.net/PhQLd/3/)

Comment: @Derija93: Well I proposed http://jsfiddle.net/PhQLd/4/, which gives what I expected, and what I *thought* the OP asked for (*I need to select the outermost td.*).

Comment: It's not just the outermost td, it's the outermost td up to the first table with a particular class. That's what makes this less than obvious.

Comment: @thatthatisis did you look at the fiddle of Derija93? looks like it is what you want.

Comment: That'll do it. @Derija93 if you care to have another accepted answer on your record, that's what I'm looking for. Otherwise, thanks for the helpful comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do something very similar to your example.  You just need to take into consideration that browsers will add a `tbody` whether you add one or not.

```
$('#targetinput').closest('.relevanttable > tbody > tr > td');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d7Zqf/1/

*I was unable to find a reliable source which mentioned which browsers do and do not add the `tbody`.  I would expect that all modern browsers do.  I tested IE9 and current FF.*

Comment: Thanks, James. I thought that should have worked and the tbody didn't occur to me to be the reason it wasn't. I'll probably use the parentsuntil solution since it's probably more reliable considering the WIDE range of browsers I have to support. (officially IE 8, but sometimes 7, opera, FF 3.x, and everything up to current)

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally suggest, though as yet untested:

```
$('#relevant_field').parents('td').last();
```

References:

- [`last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).